# run command when starting ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Every time my server running Ubuntu 16.04 starts, I need the following command to run:

**cd sushipool-linux-x64-1.3.1-avx512f
screen ./sushipool**

I read some articles about it without success.
Could someone give a light?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to run the command on startup?

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information about this site is available in the [help].

Comment: sorry.. Ken...and yes, i want run the command on startup